# Change symbol name in Mach-O

Tags: ios, binary, mach-o

I have an iOS binary that oddly uses the wrong symbol names. For example, it looks for the symbol UIProgressBar instead of UIProgressView in UIKit.framework.

Now, I need to run that binary. If I manually edit it, I get a truncated Mach-O file, and something about `__LINKEDIT` being too large.

I've looked at other questions, and have found nothing on the subject, only things about frameworks.

I also do not have the source code to this binary. My iPod is jailbroken, and this binary is not code signed, so that won't affect anything.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you *manually*  edited the binary? :O

Comment: @luk2302 It was worth a try. :P